# Arrays and strpbrk in C

Tags: c

If my array is :

```
char* String_Buffer = "Hi my name is <&1> and i have <&2> years old."
char* pos = strpbrk(String_buffer, "<");
```

Now pos is :

> " <&1> and i have <&2> years old. "

But i need "Hi my name is". How can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you track `start` separately, you can "cut out" a section of the buffer:

```
char *start = String_Buffer;
char *end = strpbrk(String_Buffer, "<");

if (end) {
    /* found it, allocate enough space for it and NUL */
    char *match = malloc(end - start + 1);

    /* copy and NUL terminate */
    strncpy(match, start, end - start);
    match[end - start] = '\0';

    printf("Previous tokens: %s\n", match);
    free(match);
} else {
    /* no match */
}
```

To walk the buffer printing each token, you'll simply hoist this into a loop:

```
char *start = String_Buffer, *end, *match;

while (start) {
    end = strpbrk(start, "<");
    if (!end) {
        printf("Last tokens: %s\n", start);
        break;
    } else if (end - start) {
        match = malloc(end - start + 1);

        /* copy and NUL terminate */
        strncpy(match, start, end - start);
        match[end - start] = '\0';

        printf("Tokens: %s\n", match);
        free(match);

        end++; /* walk past < */
    }

    /* Walk to > */
    start = strpbrk(end, ">");
    if (start) {
        match = malloc(start - end + 1); /* start > end */
        strncpy(match, end, start - end);
        match[start - end] = '\0';

        printf("Bracketed expression: %s\n", match);
        free(match);
        start++; /* walk past > */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure that the string you are working with is in modifiable memory<sup>1</sup>:

```
char String_Buffer[] = "Hi my name is <&1> and i have <&2> years old."
```

then, cut your string at the position where you found `<`:

```
char* pos = strpbrk(String_buffer, "<");
if(pos!=NULL)
{
    /* changing the '<' you found to the null character you are actually
     * cutting the string in that place */
    *pos=0;
}
```

Printing `String_Buffer` will now output `Hi my name is`. If you don't want the final space, just move `pos` backward of one element (being careful not to go before the beginning of `String_Buffer`).

---

1. In your code you declared a `char` pointer and made it point to a string literal, which is non-modifiable (that's why you normally write ***`const`*** `char * str = "asdasads";`; in this case, instead, we are initializing a local `char` array, which we can change as much as we want.

Comment: Adding the string terminator where you want to cut it, as shown in my example.

Comment: @user1558736 C strings are '\0'-terminated. That means that the character `0` means "the string ends here". If I have "abcdef" and replace "c" by "\0", I get the string "ab". That's what he is doing with `*pos = 0;`

Comment: Yes , but if String_Buffer is a long text , and now i need for example: "and i have"... How can know the position?

Comment: You can iterate this process starting from one character after the position of the last match (skipping all the characters before the first `>`), but maybe this could be done more easily with `strtok`.